# Ruby-Reading a specific bash-script file from ruby file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

```
#practice.rb
$TENANT=gets.chomp('/\p{Alnum}/')
$first = $TENANT.slice(0,1).capitalize
$second = $TENANT.slice(1..-1)
EXPORT_PASSWORD="Export-"+ $first + $second.chomp + "!"
EXPORT_FILENAME=$TENANT.chomp + ".xar"
file = File.open("/Users/..../input/exporttenant.rb", "r")
contents = file.read
puts content
output = File.open(/.../input/$TENANT.txt, "w")
$TENANT=tenant_name
file = File.open("/data/workday/wmu/input/exportTenant.properties", "r")
$line = file.readlines.select{|line| line.match('DS_ENTRY_OMS_SERVER')}
file.close
output=File.open("/data/workday/wmu/input/#{$TENANT}".chomp, 'w')
output.puts "TENANT_NAME=#{$TENANT}"
output.puts "EXPORT_PASSWORD=#{$PASSWORD}"
output.puts "EXPORT_FILENAME=#{FILENAME}"
output.puts "EXPORT_WITHOUT_TAR=N"
output.puts "BYPASS_BLOB=N"
output.puts $line
output.close
print "Export tenant created for the #{$TENANT}\n"
```

I have created one file by the name(wandarar.sh-written in bash).The wanda.sh file has commands.I want to run the wandarar.sh file from another file(practice.rb).
I want to include the same functionality what wandarar.sh file have into the practice.rb file.                                                                      How can I run this.Can someone help me with this ?

Comment: You say that you want, but what have you tried and where are u stuck? Crucial information for anyone trying to help you.

Comment: I am able to open the file exporttenant.rb but from that file I want the information of DS_ENTRY_OMS_SERVER but I cannot get that information its printing all text line .DS_ENTRY_OMS_SERVER = open("/../Desktop/input/exporttenant.rb").gets

Comment: I want to create the file with varaible name $TENANT in that directory but I cannot create it                                                                                           output = File.open(/.../input/$TENANT.txt, "w")   when executed output is: practice.rb:15: syntax error, unexpected tGVAR, expecting ')'
output = File.new(/input/$TENANT.txt, "r")
                                ^
 syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting :: or '[' or '.'
16: syntax error, unexpected tGVAR, expecting ')'
output = File.open(/input/$TENANT.txt, "w")
                                 ^

Comment: You are mixing and matching all kinds of weird naming schemes here, without seeming to realize that you *cannot do that in Ruby*. The way you decorate your variables actually has meaning, you shouldn't be using `$first` unless you actually want to create a global variable, and you shouldn't be using `EXPORT_PASSWORD` unless you actually intend to create a constant.

Comment: Hi I already created a variable its working fine. I am looking for for file open and writing

Comment: @user1642224 : The previous comment was actually an advice :D. Technically it will work, but it's very non Ruby like.

Comment: I think it will help a lot now if you can give an example of the kind of line you wish to find in the file.

Comment: Ruby isn't PHP or Perl. Don't prefix your variables with a `$`, those are global variables (you don't want that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you are getting an array, select a line which is matched your criteria.

```
file = File.open('/home/username/Documents/file.txt', 'r')

   puts file.readlines.select{|line| line.match('DS_ENTRY')}

file.close
```

Comment: I want to create a temporary file with the variable name $TENANT . for example if i give tenant name as "devi123ask". The temporary file should be created by /...../devi123ask.txt/      output=File.open("/.../$TENANT.txt", 'w')                                                          I can see file is created by $TENANT.txt(ls -ltr) but it should be created by given $TENANT variable name.  can some one help mw with this. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the [.grep](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep) method, try this:

```
file_name = "put your file name here"
lines = File.readlines(file_name)
lines.grep(/DS_ENTRY\((.*)\)/)

File.open($1, "w") { |f| f.puts "file content" }
```